# How can I sort the values of a hash in decreasing order in perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, hash

I am trying to use this code, but it attempts to sort the keys instead, which it cannot do because they are not numerical.

```
foreach my $word (sort {$b <=> $a} keys %wordHash) {
        printf ("%-20s %10d\n", $word, $wordHash{$word});
}
```

Comment: If you want values, use `values` instead of `keys`. If you want alphabetical ordering, use `cmp` instead of `<=>`.

Comment: @ooga - it's kind of unclear what the OP wants... I answered all 3 options I could think of

Comment: A key point of terminology:  You cannot sort a hash.  Hashes have no order.  What you can do is print out things that are in a hash in a given order, but the hash itself is not sorted.  This is different from PHP arrays where they have keyed lookup like Perl hashes but also are in a specific order like Perl arrays.

Comment: @AndyLester - well, if you're crafty, you CAN sort a hash (e.g. via Tied hashes) but that's a bit of an abomination and should be done only as a last resort.

Comment: I think that's irrelevant noise for what we're talking about here.  The OP doesn't want "sorted hashes", he wants the contents of the hash output in a sorted order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- If you want to print your hash **in the values order**, then you simply need to compare values in your `sort` block instead of comparing the keys themselves:

  ```
   { $wordHash{$b} <=> $wordHash{$a} } 
   # The rest of your code stands
  ```

  This works because the block used in [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) can be ANY anonymous subroutine with arbitrary logic; as long as it returns positive/0/negative values.
- If you only want sorted values irrespective of keys, even simpler (*seems kinda pointless so I assume you wanted the previous option, but just in case I'll answer this as well*):

  ```
   sort {$b <=> $a} values %wordHash
  ```
- Also, if you want to print in keys order but sorted alphabetically instead of numerically, default sort [sorts lexically](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) (same as `{ $a cmp $b }`):

  ```
   sort keys %wordHash               # sort in ascending alphanumeric
   reverse sort keys %wordHash       # sort in descending alphanumeric
   sort { $b cmp $a } keys %wordHash # same: descending alphanumeric,
                                     #   faster on large data but less readable
  ```

Comment: I suspect he is looking for `cmp`

Comment: Yes, it is, but default is also ascending sort, and he wanted descending. Which you need to do explicitly, `{ $b cmp $a }`

Comment: @TLP - Fair enough. I expanded that detail to cover ALL options.